# Javascript slideshow shows no image for one iteration

Tags: javascript, html

The slideshow shows pic1.jpg through pic8.jpg and then no image for 4 seconds and then starts back at pic1.jpg. I want it to go right back to pic1.jpg after pic8.jpg.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
var pics = ["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg", "pic4.jpg", "pic5.jpg", "pic6.jpg", "pic7.jpg", "pic8.jpg"];
var i = 1;
function changeImage() {
   var image = document.getElementById('homeslideshow');
   if (i < pics.length) {
       image.src = pics[i]
       i++;
   }
   else {
       image.src = pics[i]
       i = 0;
   }
}
</script>
```

The function is called in the html with:

```
<body onload="setInterval(function(){changeImage()}, 4000)">
```

And the slideshow is displayed with:

```
<div id="section">
   <img id="homeslideshow" src="pic1.jpg" alt="goofy" width="100%" height=auto>
</div>
```

I am a total newbie to html/css/js, so please be nice! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing your else part as `else { i = 0;image.src = pics[i];}`

Comment: Also you are missing a `;` after `image.src = pics[i]`.

Comment: That got rid of the no image but now pic1.jpg displays for 8 seconds instead of 4 after pic8.jpg. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `else` block as below

```
else {
    i = 0;
    image.src = pics[i];
}
```

as in your code, when you was setting the `image.src` before setting the value of `i` to 0, actually you were setting the image src with `pics[8]` which was not valid.

Also, **you are missing a `;` after `image.src = pics[i]`** in the `if` block.

**UPDATE**

Replace your JS as below to solve your 8 seconds problem

```
<script>
var pics = ["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg", "pic4.jpg", "pic5.jpg", "pic6.jpg", "pic7.jpg", "pic8.jpg"];
var i = 0;
function changeImage() {
   var image = document.getElementById('homeslideshow');
   if (i < pics.length-1) {
       i++;
       image.src = pics[i];
   }
   else {
       i = 0;
       image.src = pics[i];
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So then does "i < pics.length" evaluate to True for i=7? I thought this would send the code to the else block and display pics[7] or pic8.jpg and then set it back to 0.

Comment: edited the answer..change your `if` to `if (i < pics.length-1)`.

Comment: Awesome! That works perfect! Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Great...glad that it helped.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You use 4000ms delay. Remove that. 
setInterval(function(){changeImage()})

Comment: This just makes the slideshow change through each picture instantly. I want each picture to display for 4 seconds that is what the 4000 is there for. It works correctly except for between pic8.jpg (i=7) and pic1.jpg (i=0) there is 4 seconds of no image.

Comment: You can use timeout or change the delay. In my opinion a timeout would be an elegant way. That there is no Image is because of setting a src Tool early. See the other answer for more information.